# Yoast sitemap broken due to script tags

Tags: wordpress, plugins, yoast

Yoast SEO is returning an error when I access its sitemap. The file page-sitemap.xml says "error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document"

I tracked the problem down to the fact that four javascripts are referenced above the  declaration. So, we see

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/imPower-weight-loss-tools/js/jquery.tools.min.js?ver=5.0.3'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/imPower-weight-loss-tools/js/jquery-ui.js?ver=5.0.3'></script>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="//www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/css/main-sitemap.xsl"?>
```

Instead of simply

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="//www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/css/main-sitemap.xsl"?>
```

as the start to the file.

In what way can I remove these script tags so that Yoast's page-sitemap.xml file can validate?

Comment: Maybe you are enqueuing scripts incorrectly. Can you post the code where you enqueue those scripts?

Comment: The first two jQuery lines are in /wp-includes/script-loader.php

`// jQuery
 $scripts->add( 'jquery', false, array( 'jquery-core', 'jquery-migrate' ), '1.12.4' );
 $scripts->add( 'jquery-core', '/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js', array(), '1.12.4' );
 $scripts->add( 'jquery-migrate', "/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate$suffix.js", array(), '1.4.1' );`

The last two are in \wp-content\plugins\imPower-weight-loss-tools\imp-calorie.php.

`wp_register_script('imp-js-ui',IMP_CALORIE_PLUGIN_URL.'js/jquery-ui.js', array('jquery') );
  wp_register_script('imp-js-jquery-tools',IMP_CAL`...

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED: I thought the below worked, but it didn't due to some other condition I had going on. When that condition changed, this no longer worked. I've asked this as a separate question with better information [in a separate question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54586417/is-there-a-filter-or-action-to-dequeue-jquery-on-yoast-sitemaps).

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'defer_jquery_for_sitemap', 100 );
function defer_jquery_for_sitemap() {
    $url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    $isItSitemap = strpos($url, 'sitemap');
    if ($isItSitemap==false) {
        wp_script_add_data( 'jquery-core', 'async/defer' , true );
        wp_script_add_data( 'jquery-migrate', 'async/defer' , true );
    }
}
```