# Is there a filter or action to dequeue jQuery on Yoast sitemaps?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, yoast

I've added more detail from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54488753/yoast-sitemap-broken-due-to-script-tags/54557455#54557455).

Yoast SEO page-sitemap.xml is invalid XML. Showing error `Extra content at the end of the document`

I found that Yoast SEO `page-sitemap.xml` is invalid because of jquery script tags being inserted before the `<?xml>` declaration.

Like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://dev-intechrahealth.pantheonsite.io/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://dev-intechrahealth.pantheonsite.io/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1'></script>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding...
```

I do not want them added to sitemap files. I simply want my sitemap file to begin like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding...
```

What I found works is adding a bit of URL detection code to `/wp-includes/script-loader.php` that checks if the current URL is a sitemap, then conditionally loads the jquery scripts with `$scripts->add`. Like this:

```
// jQuery
$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$isItSitemap = strpos($url, 'sitemap');
if ($isItSitemap==false) {
    $scripts->add( 'jquery', false, array( 'jquery-core', 'jquery-migrate' ), '1.12.4' );
    $scripts->add( 'jquery-core', '/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js', array(), '1.12.4' );
    $scripts->add( 'jquery-migrate', "/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate$suffix.js", array(), '1.4.1' );
}
```

But that's editing core and I don't want to do that. I want this to happen in my theme's (Divi) `functions.php` so as to be preserved when I update core.

So I did this in `functions.php`:

```
/* Register jQuery but first detect if the Yoast SEO sitemap is rendering and dequeue script if so. This prevents an XML format error which is caused when <script> tags appear before the <?xml> declaration */
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dequeue_jquery_for_sitemap', 10 );
function dequeue_jquery_for_sitemap() {
$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$isItSitemap = strpos($url, 'sitemap');
if (!$isItSitemap==false) {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-core' );
    wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-migrate' );
}
}
```

I even tried `wp_deregister_script` as well:

```
wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery' );
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-core' );
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-core' );        
wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-migrate' );
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-migrate' );
```

However, this doesn't solve the problem. They still show up in the `page-sitemap.xml`.

What other way is there to achieve this? Or what am I missing?

Comment: You want to remove js file from sitemap?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yoast sitemap broken due to script tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54488753/yoast-sitemap-broken-due-to-script-tags)

Comment: Yes. I want to remove js file references from the Yoast page-sitemap.xml file that is generated dynamically. 

I'm aware of the possible duplicate. It was a post I had created earlier and thought I had solved, but I was wrong. So I re-posted with better info and then linked them. If I delete the old one, StackOverflow will deduct reputation.

Comment: SOLVED: There was an obscure add_action in a custom plugin that a vendor no longer supports that was adding the <script> tags, but it was all but impossible to detect without commenting out individual lines of code in a whole file.